# Best way to parse dump data (hex) from SOAP?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, soap, wsdl

My application is going to be receiving dump data continuously in the following manner:

3c:73:3a:45:6e:76:65:6c:6f:70:65:20:78:6d:6c:6e:73:3a:73:3d:22:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:73:63:68:65:6d:61:73:2e:78:6d:6c:73:6f:61:70:2e:6f:72:67:2f:73:6f:61:70:2f:65:6e:76:65:6c:6f:70:65:2f:22:3e:3c:73:3a:42:6f:64:79:20:78:6d:6c:6e:73:3a:78:73:69:3d:22:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:77:77:77:2e:77:33:2e:6f:72:67:2f:32:30:30:31:2f:58:4d:4c:53:63:68:65:6d:61:2d:69:6e:73:74:61:6e:63:65:22:20:78:6d:6c:6e:73:3a:78:73:64:3d:22:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:77:77:77:2e:77:33:2e:6f:72:67:2f:32:30:30:31:2f:58:4d:4c:53:63:68:65:6d:61:22:3e:3c:53:65:74:4e:61:74:69:6f:6e:61:6c:4c:69:73:74:20:78:6d:6c:6e:73:3d:22:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:77:77:77:2e:6c:67:65:2e:63:6f:6d:2f:64:64:63:22:3e:3c:6e:61:74:69:6f:6e:61:6c:4c:69:73:74:3e:3c:70:6f:72:74:6e:75:6d:62:65:72:3e:36:30:30:30:3c:2f:70:6f:72:74:6e:75:6d:62:65:72:3e:3c:73:6c:61:76:65:61:64:64:72:65:73:73:3e:37:30:30:30:3c:2f:73:6c:61:76:65:61:64:64:72:65:73:73:3e:3c:66:6c:61:67:7a:6f:6e:65:3e:32:3c:2f:66:6c:61:67:7a:6f:6e:65:3e:3c:66:6c:61:67:69:6e:64:69:76:69:73:75:61:6c:3e:35:3c:2f:66:6c:61:67:69:6e:64:69:76:69:73:75:61:6c:3e:3c:66:6c:61:67:64:69:6d:6d:69:6e:67:3e:33:3c:2f:66:6c:61:67:64:69:6d:6d:69:6e:67:3e:3c:66:6c:61:67:70:61:74:74:65:72:6e:3e:36:3c:2f:66:6c:61:67:70:61:74:74:65:72:6e:3e:3c:66:6c:61:67:67:72:6f:75:70:3e:39:3c:2f:66:6c:61

Which is just ASCII code for

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><SetNationalList xmlns="http://www.lge.com/ddc">
   <nationalList>
      <portnumber>6000</portnumber>
      <slaveaddress>7000</slaveaddress>
      <flagzone>2</flagzone>
      <flagindivisual>5</flagindivisual>
      <flagdimming>3</flagdimming>
      <flagpattern>6</flagpattern>
      <flaggroup>9</flaggroup>
    </nationalList>
</SetNationalList></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I basically need to get the values from portnumber,slaveaddress... flaggroup.

What is the best way to parse such a data in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is basically an xml structure.
Parse this xml structure in an XDocument object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx), and then do some query on it.

Take a look at Linq to XML : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

If you are not LINQ familiar, you can use something like XPath

Comment: So then I'd have to first convert that entire dump data into ASCII right? What would be the fastest and most efficient way of doing this? I'm going to have a humongous amount of dumpdata and I don't want to lose too much performance by continuously converting the data into ASCII so I gotta have a fast method.

Comment: Yes, ofc you will have to convert this into ASCII data. Take a look at the Encoding class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx ; I think all you need is here. I see soemthing like convert you hex into a string, then to ASCII

Answer (score 0):

You can either deserialize the XML into an object, for example using [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx) or you could take a look at reading the XML itself using for example [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

Comment: So then I'd have to first convert that entire dump data into ASCII right? What would be the fastest and most efficient way of doing this? I'm going to have a humongous amount of dumpdata and I don't want to lose too much performance by continuously converting the data into ASCII so I gotta have a fast method.